# C++ Calling a method inside a object using a pointer to change a member value

Tags: c++

I have a class defined something like this:

```
class ClassTwo
{
    public:
        ClassTwo();

        void UpByFour();

        ~ClassTwo();

        private:
        int numberOne;
};

ClassTwo::ClassTwo();
{
    numberOne = 5000;
};

ClassTwo::UpByFour()
{
    printf("before %d ", numberOne);
    numberOne += 400;
    printf("after %d", numberOne);
};
```

I do:

```
ClassTwo doesWork();
doesWork.UpByFour();
```

and it works.

How do I create a pointer to a ClassTwo, add an object to it and the call it's method inside another method?

I tried with

```
ClassTwo *thingOne = NULL;

void Create()
{
    ClassTwo objectOne = ClassTwo();
    thingOne = &ObjectOne;
}

int main(/*arguments*/)
{
    //unrelated things happens

    Create();

    //used printf to check if thingOne->numberOne has the right value and it does

    thingOne->UpByFour();

    //console shows "before 0 after 0" and thingOne->numberOne is some big number

}
```

Was going to create, use and destroy many ClassTwo objects, but I can't manage to get one to work.

Comment: Your `objectOne` goes away when the function exits, so you are using a "dead" object. Probably not good, long term.

Comment: Make sure you compile with warnings (e.g. `--wall`).

Comment: why do you want to use a pointer? I dont see the benefit, other than a good opportunity for lots of bugs. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: the question you need to ask is: Do you really need `NULL` as a possible value for `thingOne` ? If thats not the case there is no reason to use a pointer

Comment: I doubt `ClassTwo doesWork();` works as you expect. I'll leave it to you to figure out why ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your output

> ```
> console shows "before 0 after 0" and thingOne->numberOne is some big number
> ```

is that

When you create an object of your ClassTwo inside of the function, the scope of the variable is limited to the body of the function and the pointer pointing to the variable holds a valid value until the control of the program is in the function's body.

As soon as the control comes out of your function, the object created by you inside the class is destroyed but the pointer is still pointing to that address and hence dereferencing it is undefined

**Solution**

You need to dynamically create the objects. Dynamically created objects have a lifetime of program execution and are not bounded to scopes. So you need write something like this.

```
ClassTwo *ptr = nullptr;

void create(){

if(ptr) delete ptr;
ptr = new ClassTwo();

}
```

The above create allocated the new object a memory using **new** and the ptr holds its address, and use can use it as many times as you want, As soon as you call next *create()*, the last ptr is deleted resulting in freeing the memory and a new memory block is created and assigned to ptr for further use.

In the end, make sure to delete the last allocated memory by deleting ptr so in main()

```
...
delete ptr;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a local variable leaves scope, its DTOR is called (usually).

To avoid this, you need to place your object on the heap. This is usually done with `new` as shown in this example:

```
void Create()
{

    thingOne = new ClassTwo();
}
```

However, you need to make sure on yourself, that this action is really save (memory leaks). A better approach is like follows:

```
void Create()
{
    if(thingOne)
      delete thingOne;
    thingOne = new ClassTwo();

}
```

A good approach is setting breakpoints in the DTOR of your class and look when they get called. Or, if you do not want to have a breakpoint in it, just make a `cout` that says that the destructor was called.

Answer (score 0):

for an item to be long lasting one you should create it on the heap using dynamic allocation, prefer using `std::unique_ptr` so you will not have memory leaks.

```
thingOne->UpByFour();
```

this item was created on the stack. once the scoop of function `Create` ends the destructor of the item is called and this item is not valid

also prefer using make_unique instead of the constructor.

```
std::unique_ptr<ClassTwo> objectOne  = std::make_unique<ClassTwo>();
```